# addresses between 200 and 299. Show that there are at least two houses whose addresses are consecutive numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose there are fifty houses on a street, and that they have addresses between 200 and 299. Show that there are at least two houses whose addresses are
consecutive numbers
it is strictly between 200 and 299 
I dont even really know where to start here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_1,H_2,\dots,H_{50}$ be the addresses of the houses in order from smallest to greatest, so $H_1<H_2<\cdots <H_{50}$. If there are no two houses whose addresses are consecutive, then you know $H_{n+1} \geq H_n+2$ (equivalently, $H_n \leq H_{n+1}-2$) for all $1 \leq n< 50$. Combine this with the fact that $H_1 \geq 200$ and $H_{50} \leq 299$ to get a contradiction.